# Separate css style for img inside a

Tags: html, css

I have html code:

```
<div  class="btn-header transparent pull-right">
    <span>
        <a (click)="userInfo()" class="dropdown-toggle no-margin userdropdown">
            {{ userAccount()?.given_name }}
            <img  src="assets/img/avatars/male.png" />
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

So what this basically does is show users name and picture next to his name. Currently the picture is too big and when I try to resize it by adding `style="height: 33px"` in img tag, the users name also resizes but I only want to resize picture.

The css classes are built in from component we use so I can't show them.

Comment: Share your CSS code too

Comment: What's the problem of having a `width` and `height: auto` set on the image?

Comment: <img src="assets/img/avatars/male.png">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine. put this in your CSS declarations.

```
a img {
/*
CSS styles here
*/
}
```

Comment: a > img { ... }

Answer (score 1):

Just add your `style="height: 33px;"` on the `img` tag itself. That said, it is often preferable to add the CSS to a class, and add the class to the img tag.

Comment: @OjamaYellow That does not make much sense... What is exactly the layout that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `width` and `height` directly in `img` tag

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div  class="btn-header transparent pull-right">
    <span>
        <a (click)="userInfo()" class="dropdown-toggle no-margin userdropdown">
            {{ userAccount()?.given_name }}
            <img  src="assets/img/avatars/male.png" width="33" height="33" />
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new class for img only like this:

```html
    <style>
img.Employee{
      height:33px;
      vertical-align:middle;
    }
</style>

    <div  class="btn-header transparent pull-right">
    <span>
        <a (click)="userInfo()" class="dropdown-toggle no-margin userdropdown">
            {{ userAccount()?.given_name }}
            <img class="Employee" src="assets/img/avatars/male.png" alt="image" />
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```